# Why I cannot receive list from servlet?

Tags: java

JSP page. I want to receive an ArrayList from MainServlet. But it seems like Servlet doesn't respond at all, because it keeps sending nulls. I checked Database Layer, but it works fine.

```
<%
        HttpSession mainSession = request.getSession(false);
        User user = (User)mainSession.getAttribute("objectUser");
%>

<div class="header">
    <h1><c:out value="${sessionScope.objectUser.username}"/></h1>

</div>
<%
ArrayList<UserPost> userPosts = (ArrayList<UserPost>)request.getAttribute("ArrayListPost");%>
<div class="main">
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.ArrayListPost}" var="obj">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="blockText">
                <h1><c:out value="${obj.postHeading}"/></h1>
                <p><c:out value="${obj.postBody}"/></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </c:forEach>
```

My servlet:

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        UserPostDao userPostDao = new UserPostDao();

        HttpSession mainSession = request.getSession(false);
        User user = (User)mainSession.getAttribute("objectUser");
        try {
            ArrayList<UserPost> userPosts = userPostDao.getAllByUsername(user.getUsername());
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("ArrayListPost", userPosts);
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);


        } catch (SQLException throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Thanks!:)

Comment: I've reviewed your code. Everything is fine. Only debug could help)

Comment: You can write the object to the page, and see what;'s in the object.